# Glassfish 4.1 / validation.xml not loaded

Tags: java, xml, glassfish

I've ported an application from JEE6 to JEE7 (glassfish 3.1.2.2 to 4.1),

I've upgraded the META-INF/validation.xml with latest version (as stated here): http://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/):

```
<validation-config
        xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration validation-configuration-1.1.xsd"
        version="1.1">
    <message-interpolator>com.infomaxgroup.adaecommerce.validation.DatabaseMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
</validation-config>
```

The custom messageinterpolator is never called, so I've tried to set a name of a non existent class:

```
    <message-interpolator>foo.foo.foo.Bar</message-interpolator>
```

and tried to insert an error (xxx after the opening tag):

```
    <message-interpolatorxxx>foo.foo.foo.Bar</message-interpolator>
```

I've no exception into log, seems like that validation.xml (that my JEE6 application processes good) is not loaded at all into my ported JEE7 application...

Any idea on how to solve the issue ?

Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved from myself,

the problem was that validation.xml must be placed into META-INF/validation.xml folder of the  "ejb module", into my JEE6 application I had that file into WEB-INF folder of the "web module" (strangely the JEE6 application works good...), now my JEE7 application correctly load validation.xml configuration and works using the message interpolator, very good !